# Unique constraint over multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, normalization, denormalization, relational-algebra

Let's say we have these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE B (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    aId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES A (id),
    bId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES B (id),
    UNIQUE(aId, bId)
);
CREATE TABLE Child (
    parentId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Parent (id),
    createdOn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Is it possible to create a unique constraint on `Child` such that for all rows in `Child` at most one references a `Parent` having some value of `aId`? Stated another way can I created a unique constraint so that the join of the above tables will have no duplicate `aId`? I'm thinking not--the grammars of every database I could find seem tied to one table per constraint--but that might be a lack of imagination on my part. (De-normalizing to include `aId` on `Child` is one solution, of course.)

Comment: You can use a Trigger on Insert or Update to execute and respond to your constraint logic, but I think triggers should be an absolute last resort -- I'd rather do this in the business layer.

Comment: I agree with hamlin11 on this accept I'd rather not see this done in the business layer, but with a database trigger in most cases.

Comment: BUsiness layer would be the worst possible palace to put such logic, if it is too smplex for a constraint a trigger is the right way to go. It must of course be a properly written trigger that performs well(badly written triggers are what give triggers a bad rep).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following. You have to create a redundant UNIQUE constraint on `(id, aId)` in Parent (SQL is pretty dumb isn't it?!).

```
CREATE TABLE Child
(parentId INTEGER NOT NULL,
 aId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FOREIGN KEY (parentId,aId) REFERENCES Parent (id,aId),
createdOn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

Possibly a much better solution would be to drop parentId from the Child table altogether, add `bId` instead and just reference the Parent table based on `(aId, bId)`:

```
CREATE TABLE Child
(aId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 bId INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (aId,bId) REFERENCES Parent (aId,bId),
createdOn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

Is there any reason why you can't do that?

Comment: I like the second approach.  No need for triggers, tables are normalized. The `(aId,bId)` could be used as `PRIMARY KEY` of `Child` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `aId` could be used as `PRIMARY KEY` of `Child`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this would be to do away with the `Child` table altogether and put the `createdOn` column in the `Parent` table, without the `NOT NULL` constraint.  All you are saying is that one `Parent` entry can have zero or one (but not more) `createdOn` values.  You don't need a separate table for that.  The fact that it is not easy or obvious to do otherwise partially proves my point. ;-) SQL usually works out that way.

Comment: But that wouldn't enforce the uniqueness of aId. The key in the parent table is (aId, bId) not aId.